# Tub Faucet leak when hot water from another source is running

Tags: bathroom

I have a tub/shower combo with a single faucet handle in my upstairs bathroom. The tub faucet leaks a weak stream of water ONLY when hot water is turned on anywhere else in the house.

Answer (score 2):

I am a little reluctant to post this as an answer since you didn't provide the make/model of the faucet.
However, there is a mixing valve in a single-handled faucet that is pressure sensitive. When hot water runs somewhere in the house it may reduce the pressure on the hot side of the mixing valve causing the cold side to release water. This shouldn't happen on a properly functioning valve. You might solve it by replacing the springs/seals in the faucet.